# Euro sign becomes â‚¬ when I export a table to csv with jQuery

Tags: jquery, csv, export

When I make a export with the following code: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lce7s8t/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div id="dvData">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Column One</th>
            <th>Column Two</th>
            <th>Column Three</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>€ 100,0</td>
            <td>row1 Col2</td>
            <td>row1 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>€ 120,99</td>
            <td>row2 Col2</td>
            <td>row2 Col3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>€ 120,99</td>
            <td>row3 Col2</td>
            <td>row3 Col3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

        var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),

            // Temporary delimiter characters unlikely to be typed by keyboard
            // This is to avoid accidentally splitting the actual contents
            tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), // vertical tab character
            tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), // null character

            // actual delimiter characters for CSV format
            colDelim = '";"',
            rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

            // Grab text from table into CSV formatted string
            csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                var $row = $(row),
                    $cols = $row.find('td');

                return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                    var $col = $(col),
                        text = $col.text();

                    return text.replace('"', '""'); // escape double quotes

                }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

            }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

            // Data URI
            csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8;,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

        $(this)
            .attr({
            'download': filename,
                'href': csvData,
                'target': '_blank'
        });
    }

    // This must be a hyperlink
    $(".export").on('click', function (event) {
        // CSV
        exportTableToCSV.apply(this, [$('#dvData>table'), 'export.csv']);

        // IF CSV, don't do event.preventDefault() or return false
        // We actually need this to be a typical hyperlink
    });
});
```

The output looks like:

[image: Example output I get]

But I want the output to look like:

[image: Example output I want]

How can I achieve that? The charset is set to 'UTF-8'. UTF-8 contains the euro sign right? So why do I get â‚¬ as output?

Answer (score 0):

Is you're html file using UTF-8 encoding ?

If you're using an other one you can get this result

Comment: I use <meta charset="utf-8"> in my head. So it is the same encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with datatables and the Euro Symbol (â‚¬ instead of €).
Dollar looks good. Euro and Pound not.

But this happends only when I generate the excel with Firefox. If i do with Chrome  or IE it is ok.

I assumed it is caused for the encoding of the browser. I force the encoding of the file using charset utf8.

```
extend: 'excelHtml5',
charset: 'UTF-8',
bom: true,
customize: function( xlsx ) {
var sheet = xlsx.xl.worksheets['sheet1.xml'];
             
        $('row c[r^="I"]', sheet).attr( 's', '57' );
        $('row c[r^="J"]', sheet).attr( 's', '58' );
        $('row c[r^="K"]', sheet).attr( 's', '59' );
        $('row c[r^="L"]', sheet).attr( 's', '59' );
        },
text: '<i class="fas fa-file-excel"></i> Excel',
className: 'consultButton',
messageTop: msgExport,
filename: 'INFORME_'+dateFormatFile,
exportOptions: {
columns: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 , 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
                            
}
```

[Firefox result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWLoO.png)